# Recognize A^n B^n language in Prolog with no arithmetics

Tags: prolog, grammar, dcg, automata

How to recognize A^n B^n language in Prolog without arithmetics and for any A, B where A != B?

With known A = a and B = b we could write

```
% For each 'a' save 'b' in a list, then check 
% whether constructed list is equal to the rest of input list

anbn(L) :- anbn(L, []). 

anbn(L, L). 

anbn([a|L],A) :- anbn(L, [b|A]).
```

For any A and B I was thinking of a solution starting with

```
anbn(L) :- anbn(L, []).

anbn([H|L],[]) :- anbn(L,[H]). % save an element

anbn([H|L], [H|A]) :- anbn(L, [H,H|A]). % make sure front elements are the same
```

so that the first elements are all the same, but than I don't see an elegant way of checking whether all elements in the rest of the list are the same and different than the elemenets in the front.

I could check whether the rest is as long as the stored list and then whether it only consists of the second type elements but I believe I'm overcomplicating the problem and there exists a short and simple solution.

Comment: Why aren't you using definite clause grammars?

Comment: @larsmans I tried a solution with a DCG but the requirements of arbitrary A's and B's and no arithmetic made the solution not much better than normal notation. Can you please show your solution?

Comment: I may be wrong, but a^n b^n it's not a *regular* language.

Comment: @Boris: `s --> []. s --> [a], s, [b].` then add two arguments to `s` and make two minor changes to the second rule. (I'm trying not to give away the answer.)

Comment: @CapelliC: no, it's not, why?

Comment: @larsmans: I was referring to the tag automata, seems inappropriate.

Comment: @CapelliC: aⁿbⁿ is context-free, so it can be recognized by a push-down automaton.

Comment: @larsmans Never heard about DCG until now but still, I wanted to solve problem myself - not hand it to some magical blackbox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: back to the original solution, and sticking to it:

```
anbn(List) :- List = [] -> true; List = [A|Rest], a(Rest, A, 0).

a([A|Rest], A, N) :- !, a(Rest, A, s(N)).
a([B|Rest], _, N) :- b(Rest, B, N).

b([B|Rest], B, s(N)) :- b(Rest, B, N).
b([], _, 0).
```

It is iterative, it does not create choice-points, it is obvious, and it is correct, if all elements of the list are ground.

Comment: works ok. yours, as mine (and larsmans'), accepts `[1,1,1,2,2,X]`.

Comment: @WillNess yes, as well as [A,a,b,B] and so on. I don't know how to solve this short of adding a `nonvar` requirement.

Comment: or maybe this doesn't need solving. :) (CapelliC's answer too).

Comment: @Boris That's what I've been looking for :) A bit long but still elegant.

Answer (score 8):

Use a definite clause grammar.

```
s(_, _) --> [].
s(A, B) --> [A], s(A, B), [B].
```

Demo:

```
?- phrase(s(1, 2), X).
X = [] ;
X = [1, 2] ;
X = [1, 1, 2, 2] ;
X = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] .
```

Comment: Very nice, +1. In contrast to other solutions posted here, yours also works correctly for the most general query, `?- phrase(s(X,Y), Ls).`. Notice though that you do not yet satisfy OP's requirement that `X` and `Y` be distinct. Use `dif/2` in the first rule. One should always use the `phrase/2` (or `phrase/3`) interface to DCGs because the translation of DCGs to Prolog predicates may change depending on the Prolog implementation or version.

Comment: The only solution that doesn't burn my eyes. :) +1

Comment: @mat: I read the A!=B as a requirement that the solution work in that case, not that it is actually enforced. I removed the usage example without `phrase/2`, though.

Comment: @mat: Also, I just tried your suggestion of putting a `dif` in the first rule and that backtracks forever on `phrase(s(1,1),S)`. The constraint should really be handled outside of the grammar/recursion.

Comment: @mat "works correctly ... do not yet satisfy " that's a self-contradiction. "most general query `phrase(s(X,Y), Ls)` with an uninstantiated `Ls` is contradictory to the stated requirement, `X\=Y`. With instantiated `Ls`, my (and probably others') answer works correctly.

Comment: @larsmans the requirement is "to recognize `A^nB^n for any A, B where A != B`". That means that the case where `A=B` must be rejected. your answer doesn't reject such case. (it is easy to amend it so that it does, of course, although it might not be easy for the OP).

Comment: @WillNess I'm afraid lars still has the trophy. :)

Comment: @larsmans: For this I would simply add `dif/2` also to the second rule.

Comment: @larsmans That's a nice and short solution even though it just delegates the problem :p Anyway, how  to add the dif/2 here? if I just put it like this `s(A, B) --> [A], s(A, B), [B], dif(A,B).` I get error `Existence error in user:dif/4` for `phrase(s(1, 2), X).`

Comment: @Legat: you might write a helper predicate, e.g. `anbn(A,B,S) :- dif(A,B), phrase(s(A,B), S).`

Answer (score 2):

It is common for DCGs that naked variables are rewrapped
as phrase/3 during translation. So that one can implement
A^n B^n not only for when A and B are terminals, but also
when A and B are arbitrary DCGs goals.

Here is the code for that:

```
 s(_,_) --> [].
 s(A,B) --> A, s(A,B), B.
```

Here one sees the translation that is done by SWI-Prolog.
As one can see the naked variables have been converted
to phrase/3 goals:

```
 ?- listing.
 s(_, _, A, A).
 s(A, C, B, F) :-
    phrase(A, B, D),
    s(A, C, D, E),
    phrase(C, E, F).
```

Here is a sample run, for terminals A and B:

```
 ?- phrase(s("alfa","beta"),X), atom_codes(Y,X).
 X = [],
 Y = '' ;
 X = [97, 108, 102, 97, 98, 101, 116, 97],
 Y = alfabeta ;
 X = [97, 108, 102, 97, 97, 108, 102, 97, 98|...],
 Y = alfaalfabetabeta ;
 X = [97, 108, 102, 97, 97, 108, 102, 97, 97|...],
 Y = alfaalfaalfabetabetabeta .
```

Here is a sample run, for some DCG goals as A and B:

```
  bit --> "0".
  bit --> "1".

  ?- length(L,8), phrase(s(("(",bit),(bit,")")),L), atom_codes(R,L).
  L = [40, 48, 40, 48, 48, 41, 48, 41],
  R = '(0(00)0)' ;
  L = [40, 48, 40, 48, 48, 41, 49, 41],
  R = '(0(00)1)' ;
  L = [40, 48, 40, 48, 49, 41, 48, 41],
  R = '(0(01)0)' ;
  Etc..
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simpler than that:

```
anbn(L) :- append(As, Bs, L), maplist(ab, As, Bs).
ab(a, b).
```

*EDIT:* This is easily generalized to arbitrary literals.

```
anbn(L) :- L = [A|_], append(As, Bs, L), maplist(ab(A), As, Bs).
ab(A, A, B) :- A \== B.
```

*EDIT:* after Will Ness noting that's bugged: what I meant was

```
anbn(L) :- append([A|As], [B|Bs], L), A \= B, maplist(ab(A, B), As, Bs).
ab(A, B, A, B).
```

Comment: dif/2 it's a rather sophisticated library builtin. Surely more difficult to implement where not available, WRT maplist/3

Comment: Maybe we are stressing StackOverflow moving too fast :)

Answer (score 0):

```
anbn( [] ) :- !.
anbn( L ) :- L=[A|_], copy_half( L,L, Z,Z, A,_V). % Z is second half
copy_half( [A|B], [_,_|C], [V|D], Z, A,V) :- !, copy_half( B,C, D,Z, A,V).
copy_half( Z,     [],      [],    Z, A,V) :- A \== V.
```

Equivalent to

```
anbn_verboten(L):- L = [] ;
  length(L,N), N2 is N div 2, length(X,N2), length(Y,N2), append(X,Y,L), 
  L=[P|_], Y=[Q|_], P \= Q.`.
```