# Prolog program to recognize context free grammar a^n b^n

Tags: prolog, context-free-grammar, dcg

Using **Prolog** I'm trying to write a *predicate that recognizes context free grammar* and returns `true` *if the input list matches the CFG*.
The alphabet of the input consists only of `a,b`.
The CFG i'm trying to match is

```
S-> TT
T -> aTb | ab
```

I'm not quite sure how to implement this, mainly the T rule.

```
s(S0,S):-t(S0,S),t(S1,S).
t(S0,S):-S0 = a, t(S1,S), S1 = b; S0 = a, S1 = b.

match([H|T] :- s(H,T).
```

So if I query `[a, a, b, b]` it should return `true`.
However, I'm just getting an infinite loop.
I'm not quite sure how to implement the `a^n b^n` rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recognize A^n B^n language in Prolog with no arithmetics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416153/recognize-an-bn-language-in-prolog-with-no-arithmetics), which can easily be specialized to handle this; the gist of it is, "use DCGs".

Comment: This question was asked yesterday. Please spend thirty seconds searching for an answer that may already exist before asking.

Answer (score 3):

I would write the CFG in this way:

```
S -> T
T -> a T b | {epsilon}
```

that translates directly to a DCG:

```
s --> t.
t --> [].
t --> a, t, b.
```

Note I swapped the epsilon rule, to get the ability to generate phrases.

Translating that DCG by hand :

```
s(S0,S) :- t(S0,S).
t(S0,S0).
t(S0,S) :- S0=[a|S1], t(S1,S2), S2=[b|S].
```

Yields

```
?- phrase(s,L).
L = [] ;
L = [a, b] ;
L = [a, a, b, b] ;
L = [a, a, a, b, b, b] ;
...
```